# XGrabKeyboard() is not taking keyboard inout for a particular window in x11

Tags: c, keyboard, window, x11, xorg

I ran a simple C code that at first prints all the active windows and asks the user to choose a window to which the keyboard input should be conveyed.

I cam across the XGrabKeyboard() function in which I can specify the window which can grab the keyboard. It is functioning properly.

For example I set the focus to the text editor and when I run the code, the caret starts blinking in the text editor. But the problem is that it receives o input and behaves as if the keyboard is frozen.

My question is what exactly is XGrabKeyboard() doing? Is it used to just grab the control of the keyboard, or can it be used to associate the keyboard completely with a window and start doing any keyboard activities in that window ? Or should always the DefaultRootWindow() be grabbed?

I came across many questions, but they are not explaining what I actually need.

About XGrabKeyboard() : https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKeyboard.html

```
// list holds window IDs received from a winlist function
list = (Window*)winlist(d,&len);
printf("And the window indices and  names are...\n");
for (i=0;i<(int)len;i++) {
    name = winame(d,list[i]);
    printf("-->index = %d\t%s<--\n",i, name);
    free(name);
}
int x;
printf("Select the window for which Keyboard should be grabbed (0 indexed) ");
scanf("%d",&x);

if(XGrabKeyboard(d, list[x], False, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime)!=0)//GrabSuccess)
printf("Keyboard grab failed for window = %s", winame(d, list[x]));
else
{
printf("Keyboard Grab Successful\n");
sleep(10);
}
```